# Language Based Scanning in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm developing a twitter client (YES, another one) for the RTL languages.

How can a UILabel alignment be configured depending on the language of a tweet. So if language of the tweet is Arabic for example the alignment would be UITextAlignmetRight and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the [textAlignment property](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW15) of the UILabel in code:

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: This question is not specific to the iPhone and/or UILabel. You are asking: "Given a string, how do I determine what language it uses?". The best you can probably do is look for certain key characters or character frequencies, but you may get better answers if you ask a new question worded as I have to get a larger/different audience.